# How to concatenate JavaScript generated with HtmlHelper extension inside PartialViews and add to parent View?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, partial-views

I have 2 PartialViews inside a parent View.

In these 2 PartiaViews I generate some JavaScript code which needs to be included to the bottom of the parent View.

Here is the HtmlHelper extension which generates some JavaScript in the PartialViews.

```
public static MvcHtmlString KO_ObjectFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper)
{
    String str = "some javascript code";
    return MvcHtmlString.Create(str);
}
```

This is the parent View (main View)

```
...
//First Partial View
<% Html.RenderPartial("_PartialViewFirst"); %>

//Second Partial View
<% Html.RenderPartial("_PartialViewSecond"); %>

//Here I need to display the JavaScript from the PartialViews
<script type="text/javascript">
   <%: Html.FunctionToConcatenateJavaScript() %>
</script>
...
```

**What would be the right approach?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a Stack to push and pop scripts in the HttpContext:

```
public static class HtmlExtensions
{
    private const string ScriptsKey = "__scripts__";

    public static MvcHtmlString KO_ObjectFor<TModel>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper)
    {
        var stack = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[ScriptsKey] as Stack<string>;
        if (stack == null)
        {
            stack = new Stack<string>();
            htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[ScriptsKey] = stack;
        }
        String str = "some javascript code";
        stack.Push(str);

        return new HtmlString("some code that the helper needs to generate and output to the view");
    }

    public static IHtmlString FunctionToConcatenateJavaScript(this HtmlHelper htmlHelper)
    {
        var stack = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Items[ScriptsKey] as Stack<string>;
        if (stack == null)
        {
            return MvcHtmlString.Empty;
        }

        var scriptTag = new TagBuilder("script");
        scriptTag.Attributes["type"] = "text/javascript";
        var sb = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var script in stack)
        {
            sb.AppendLine(script);
        }
        scriptTag.InnerHtml = sb.ToString();

        return new HtmlString(scriptTag.ToString());
    }
}
```

then you could push:

```
<%= Html.KO_ObjectFor(x => x.Foo) %>
<%= Html.KO_ObjectFor(x => x.Bar) %>
...
```

and then pop em all in the master:

```
<%= Html.FunctionToConcatenateJavaScript() %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could do like this:

Partial 1:

```
@{
    ViewBag.JS = @Html.KO_ObjectFor(firstJs);
}
```

Partial 2:

```
@{
    ViewBag.JS += @Html.KO_ObjectFor(secondJs);
}
```

Main:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   @ViewBag.JS
</script>
```

Sorry for razor syntax